# Trouble getting Express/React routes to work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm just learning Express/React and I'm trying to get set up with routes and basic database connections. I suspect I'm missing something very simple. I've tried to boil it down to the following.

**Backend**

server.js:

```
require('dotenv').config({path: '../.env'});
const mysql = require('mysql');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const users = require('./routes/api/users');
app.use('/api/users', users);

const events = require('./routes/api/events');
app.use('/api/events', events);

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
});

db.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('MySQL Connected!');
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

/routes/api/events.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// GET api/events
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send({id: "1", name: "hi"});
});

module.exports = router;
```

**Frontend**

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EventList from './components/EventList';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <EventList/>
        </div>)
  }
}

export default App;
```

/components/EventList.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class EventList extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            events: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/events')
             .then(events => {
                this.setState({events: events.data})
             })
             .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    render() {
        var events = this.state.events;
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Events:</p>
                <ul>
                    { events.map(({ id, name }) => (
                        <li>{name}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default EventList;
```

The error I get is `http://localhost:3000/api/events 500 (Internal Server Error)`. What am I missing? I have truly scoured all of the docs I can find, but I'm not quite getting it.

**Edit**
I haven't changed anything, but now I'm getting a `404 (Not Found)` instead. I had been getting a 500 for awhile, so it wasn't a momentary fluke. I'm not sure what could have changed.

**Update**
It may help to know that the .env variables I'm pointing to are actually for a remote MySQL database (i.e., `DB_HOST` != localhost, but a remote URL). Eventually, I'd like to connect the GET call on the `events` route to that db, but since it doesn't work with what I have here I figured my first issue to solve was upstream. As noted in comments, the `PORT` var I'm loading in is 3306. When I start the server, it says it's listening on 3306 as expected.

Comment: Are you getting any error on the console of the express app ?

Comment: @Muljayan I wasn't, but then after a period of time I did get the following:  
```events.js:174
[0]       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
[0]       ^
[0]
[0] Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.```

It's very strange because I hadn't touched anything. See also my edit above -- I'm now getting a 404 instead of a 500.

Comment: On which port you start express server? I think you started it on 5000 port and when you call from front end on 3000.

Comment: You are probably getting a 404 for localhost:3000/api because your express server is running on port 5000.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I'm getting the port from a .env file, and the port is 3306. When I start the server it says it's listening on 3306.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are running your server on port 5000 and front on port 3000. if you request events with **http://localhost:5000/api/events** instead of **/api/events**, you would get 200 status code with your json data.

```js
// as is
axios.get('/api/events')

// to be
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/events')
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. I'm getting the port from a .env file, and the port is 3306. When I start the server it says it's listening on 3306.  

I tried `axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/events')` and `axios.get('http://localhost:3306/api/events')` to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried calling 'http://localhost:3306/api/events' on a browser? Do you still get a status code 404?

Could you check the port your front server running on?

Comment: When I try `localhost:3306/api/events` I get "This site cannot be reached" (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`). I'm pretty sure my frontend is running on localhost:3000 -- the page loads fine, just not the expected data from the GET request.

Answer (score 0):

You could try typing componentDidMount function like this.

```
componentDidMount = async () =>{
//like this
}
```

In addition, I would recommend making the GET ALL its own function so you could just invoke in the componentDidMount function. whenever you run another CRUD action it will automatically update your events for you and instead of setting state every time you can invoke the this.getEvents() again to update it that way.

```
componentDidMount = async () =>{ 
  this.getEvents()
 }
```

Also you need to add this package (npm install cors) its so you can connect your api to your frontend.

Import it like this in your server.js file

```
const cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions, but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a proxy inside package.json in frontend like this.
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Please see my update on the original post.

Comment: @user6647072 in postman check your api if it does work then it's the proxy.I don't think that mysql has anything to do with this issue.You need the proxy anyway because your front and back are not on the same port.

Comment: Hmm I added `"proxy": "http://localhost:3306"` and postman gives me: `Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/events from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3306 (ECONNREFUSED).` I've also added cors as one person suggested, if that helps.

Comment: @user6647072 Dude port 3306 is for mysql. React talks to express not mysql.Use http://localhost:5000.And do not forget this proxy is for react project not express.Postman doesn't know about this proxy.

Comment: Ok, yes, I think this is where I was getting confused. It works now (with 3306 not 5000 -- 5000 is just a default in case the .env isn't there, it's not actually used. I'm not sure why I was getting a connection refused error before as the same thing is working now.